# MAUI DEP0840 Warning on Windows Machine after Project Name change

Tags: maui

Trying to run my MAUI app on windows and I am getting following warning:

```
DEP0840: Project 'XXX' requires packages 
'MicrosoftCorporationII.WinAppRuntime.Main.1.1_8wekyb3d8bbwe' and  
'MicrosoftCorporationII.WinAppRuntime.Singleton_8wekyb3d8bbwe' with version >= 
    '1005.616.1651.0'. These packages should be installed on first run, if not please 
    visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2222757 for installation instructions."
```

Tried (re-)installing WindowsAppSDK and checked with
`(get-appxpackage micro*win*appruntime* -AllUsers).packagefullname`
that all WinAppRuntimes atr installed in higher version Main e.g. MicrosoftCorporationII.WinAppRuntime.Main.1.2_2000.802.31.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe

How can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: Can you build and deploy successfully? I tried to change the project name but the warning didn't appear.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Yeah, it runs fine. it's just this warning that bugs me. Is there a way to reset build and deployment status, to make it as if you build and run it for the first time? this would most likely solve the warning

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I get the same error as well, was trying the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/build-blazor-hybrid/ exercise using VS 17.6.1.. My output of the `(get-appxpackage micro*win*appruntime* -AllUsers).packagefullname` contains three versions including the one that the warning states.

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild or rename it as the name previous?

Comment: I used VS 17.5.5 and didn't get this waring. @RuneG

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I made a copy in Windows Explorer of the whole project. then I went into the solution file and changed all the names. Finally in VS, I changed all names in the entire solution and then this warning popped up. How can I "clean and rebuild" (aka run it as if it were the first time}? I guess this would solve the issue.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Tried clean, rebuild and everything and it went away, however when I started a debug in VS the warning came back.

Comment: @canedha right click on your project and then select the clean.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Thanks, will try! Will this also delete already stored Preferences? sorry for stupid question, I'm completely new to VS/Maui

Comment: @canedha No, this value is stored in the device, clean and rebuild will not delete it.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT do you know how to reset/clean the preferences as well?

Comment: You can call the `Preference.Clear()` method to reset/clean the preference. And for the android and ios, you can uninstall the app on the device to do that. In addition, did the clean and rebuild make the warning disappear? @canedha

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I have to check later today. thanks for all the help and input!

Comment: You are welcome. Looking forward to your feedback.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT the clean did not do the trick. i Ended up creating a new project from scratch and copy pasted the classes etc.

Comment: And after that the warning disappeared?

Comment: yes, after that it disappeared